# What exactly does $g^2(x)$ mean

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I know there's (kind of?) some controversy as to what $g^2(x)$ means — it could be $g(g(x))$, or $(g(x))^2$ or even $g''(x)$. I'm taking a calculus course and assumed that $g^2(x)$ meant $g''(x)$, but it turns out that the solution saw this as $(g(x))^2$.

Here's the problem if it will clarify things:

> If $P(x) = g^2(x)$, then $P'(x)$ equals...

(of course, there's a table given with values of g and g' accompanying the problem and answer choices, but I'm not including them here because of copyright.)

So in general, is there any way I can determine which one exactly the problem means when $g^2(x)$ appears?

Comment: If the problem is referring to the $n$th derivative of a function, usually it is denoted as $g^{(n)}(x)$.

Comment: Usually when I refer to the $n$th derivative with a superscript, I enclose it in parentheses. I.e., $g^{\prime\prime}(x) = g^{(2)}(x)$.

Comment: Well, in my opinion that's based on context. If the end of that sentence is $g^3(x)$, then I guess you know what is being spoken about. Generally, in my experience, for the derivative, we usually use a bracket around 2 for derivatives i.e. $g''(x) = g^{(2)}(x)$

Comment: I think it's a good bet that $g^2(x)$ will always mean $g(x)^2$ in your calculus course.   I have never seen it used to mean the second derivative, as others have already noted.

Comment: ...$2g(x)g'(x)$

Answer (score 3):

If it means $g''(x) $, you should write
$$g^{(2)}(x) $$

If it is $g(x).g (x) $, you will write
$$(g(x))^2$$

so $g^2 (x) $ means $$g (g (x)) $$

Comment: However, with functions $g^2(x)$ often also means $(g(x))^2$.  Think of $\sin$.  $\sin^2(x)$ almost always means $(\sin(x))^2$.

Comment: However, $\sin^{-1}(x)$ mostly has the opposite convention, so it does **not** mean usually mean $((\sin(x))^{-1}$, the cosecant of $x$.

Answer (score 2):

It usually depends on the circumstance the problem is situated in.

For example, if you're doing calculus, it's probably good notation to avoid using $g^2$ to denote the 2nd derivative and simply use $g''$ as this avoids confusion.
If you're doing something like linear algebra, the notation $T^n$ would probably mean matrix multiplication, i.e., $T^n = T\circ T\circ \cdots \circ T$.

For me, I usually use the following convention:

- $g(x)^2$ to denote square of $g(x)$
- $g^2(x)$ to denote $g\circ g$
- $g^{(2)}(x)$ to denote the 2nd derivative

Of course, there are probably special cases in which I may abuse notation just for sake of simplicity (e.g $\cos^2(x)$ is the square of $\cos$), but I think it's good practice to keep your notation uniform throughout your notes and textbooks. I would believe that most authors abide by this rule and would at least mention it in their text if they're changing notation.